# How can I group two rows in a cross tab query in MS - Access?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I currently have crosstab query in MS Access that groups data by the field "Type". This field is the row header in my crosstab query.

**The 3 "Type" values are:**

Equipment, Optional, Parts

I would like to combine the values of the Optional and Parts rows into one row (called Together) and present the crosstab query with just two rows:

Equipment

Together

How can this be done? Basically how can I group two rows in a cross tab query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the column displaying your `Type` field, use an `iif` expression to output `Together` if the value of the field is either `Optional` or `Parts`, else output the value of the field e.g.:

```sql
NewType: iif(YourTable.Type in ('Optional','Parts'),'Together',YourTable.Type)
```

Alternatively:

```sql
NewType: iif(YourTable.Type='Optional' or YourTable.Type='Parts','Together',YourTable.Type)
```